# Responsive Design on Samsung Devices onyl displays background?

Tags: android, html, css, browser

I have a big problem with my design, which I adjusted for mobile devices.

I tested it on my iPhone and on my iPad and also on Windows Phone, since I have no Android devices I can't test it on them. But I asked a friend to test it on his Samsung Galaxy S3 and also found a website where you can test it on Samsung Galaxy S5, I saw that it looks really strange on Samsung devices.

The only thing you see on the screen is a small part of the background, and no div from the website ..

I tested also many viewport settings and CSS media query settings, but nothing worked on the Samsung devices and at this point I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Here is my code, if you need it:

```
meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (min-device-width: 560px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

And here is a screenshot: http://www.nfs-serie.at/gallery/without/549993baed99e_IMG_1268.JPG

Does anyone else have this issue or a solution for it because I really don't know why the site is not showing right on Samsung devices and all other devices work like they should.

Edit: tested some more and found out that this is not a problem with the media queries, the site without media queries is also not shown on Samsung devices. You only see the background image and I don't know why at this point .. trying to figure out what's the problem here ..

Answer (score 0):

Not all Samsung devices support media queries. That's your problem I believe. This could be very helpful for you: http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html

You can test this site on your device, and see which media queries work.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem is I have no Samsung device to test it .. but if this is a problem of the media queries on Samsung devices how can I display the page right on this devices?
Can I detect with PHP if its a Samsung browser or only Android browser?